# Getting ElementNotVisibleException : Using Selenium WebDriver in MakeMyTrip.com for Date Picker

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click a particular date in makemytip.com. I have written the below code. Everything works fine. Except I am unable to select the date. I can navigate to the month which ever I want but not able to select the date. Thanks for the help in advance.

when I run the below program, I get the following error

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

```
package com;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Calendar_MMT {
    static WebDriver d;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
     d = new FirefoxDriver();
     d.manage().window().maximize();
        d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        d.get("http://makemytrip.com");
        d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='start_date_sec']/span[1]/span[1]")).click();
    selectDate("02/03/2016");
    }


    public static void selectDate(String date) throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dateToBeSelected = df.parse(date);
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        String monthYearDisplayed = d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/div/div")).getText();
        System.out.println(monthYearDisplayed);

        String month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(dateToBeSelected);
        String year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(dateToBeSelected);
        String day = new SimpleDateFormat("d").format(dateToBeSelected);
        String monthYearToBeSelected = month+" "+year;
        System.out.println(monthYearToBeSelected);

        while(true){
        if(monthYearToBeSelected.equals(monthYearDisplayed)){

// I FEEL BELOW LINE HAS PROBLEM
                d.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='"+day+"']")).click();
                System.out.println("Found and Selected");
                break;

            }else{ //navigate to correct month and year
                if(dateToBeSelected.after(currentDate)){
                    d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[2]/div/a/span")).click();
                }else{
                    d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/div/a/span")).click();
                }

            }
            monthYearDisplayed = d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/div/div")).getText();
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebElement.click()`does not work because for some reason the WebDriver thinks that the web element is not visible. To verify this you can execute:

```
WebElement dayElement = d.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='" + day + "']"));
System.out.println("isDisplayed: " + dayElement.isDisplayed()); //this will always print false
```

To bypass the visibility check you can execute the click via javascript:

```
WebElement dayElement = d.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='" + day + "']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) d;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", dayElement);
```

Comment: Thanks. As of now, I am not preferring to use Java script. Any possibility to do without js?

Comment: This code is java. What I meant is: you can execute the javascript using the WebDriver javascript interface. Or do you want to avoid  that?

Comment: Yeah cyril. Right now I want to avoid javascript. (Sorry if I am wrong or something)

Comment: Yes. I have checked and it is not visible. How do I make it visible and click?

Answer (score 0):

There is something I noticed is that your element is overlapped by it's parent (td) and hence we aren't able to access it directly. Hence let's try accessing the parent (td) tag directly.

There are two ways now:

First one is directly access element using some of it's property:

```
d.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@fare-date='2-2-2016']")).click();
```

Second might be a customized way that you want, with a variable getting passed.

```
List<WebElement> e = d.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@data-handler='selectDay']"));
for(WebElement we:e){     
 if(we.getText().equals(day)){
    we.click();
    break;
 }
}
```

Notice that here we may not able able to identify that parent using the *text()* function directly in the locator since the text is contained withing the child tag. So we are using **getText()** instead.

What this function does is that it stores all the parent cells into a list and check the contents of each one by one unless the desired value is matched.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Explicit wait might help here

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

Source: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp